# Необычный запрос mysql (система друзей)?

Tags: php, mysql

> Есть таблица друзей если друг добавил друга отображается в виде add_fri = 0,friend = 1 означает что пользователь с id 0 добавил друга с id 1
>
> Как сделать так чтобы добавлении проверяла если есть списке то написало "Игрок уже ваш друг"

```
$friend = $_GET['add_fri'];
$f = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `db_users` WHERE steam_id = '$friend' "));
$add = $_SESSION['steam_id'];
$frien = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `friends` WHERE add_fri = '$add'");
while ($friends = mysql_fetch_array($frien))
{
if ($friends['friend'] == $$_GET['add_fri'])
{
echo "<div class='status-error'>Игрок (".$f['username'].") уже есть в друзьях.</div>
<script>$('.status-error').slideDown('slow');
setTimeout(function() { 
$('.status-error').slideUp('slow'); 
}, 3000);
</script>";
}
else if (!$friends['friend'] == $_GET['add_fri'])
{
echo "<div class='status-accept'>Игрок (".$f['username'].") был добавлен в друзья.</div>
<script>$('.status-accept').slideDown('slow');
setTimeout(function() { 
$('.status-accept').slideUp('slow');
}, 3000);
</script>"; 
$fri = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("INSERT INTO friends (add_fri,friend)    VALUES ('$add','$friend')"));
}
}
```

Comment: сделать уникальный индекс по полям add_fri и friend и ловить ошибку  нарушения уникальности после при попытке добавить френда. Если других ограничений уникальности нет (скорей всего это так), то сразу ясно в чем дело.

Comment: Советуете сделать Primary key?

Comment: Поля же работают так: add_fri = 0 friend = 1, add_fri = 0 friend = 2,Если я сделаю примери то они друг друга не добавят же

Comment: Можно и примари. Тоже уникальный. Код ошибки SQL если не ошибаюсь 23505. Добавят. Уникальность или примари по двум полям. Уникальная должна быть пара. (0, 1) != (0, 2)

Comment: Если я это сделаю то один игрок не сможет добавить больще одного друга.

Comment: Ну как не сможет, если сможет? CONSTRAINT composite_pk  PRIMARY KEY (add_fri, friend), И см. предыдущий комент

Comment: И как мне это проверить сделать так чтобы если успешно добавил написало то написал успешно добавлен если нет то увас уже есть в друзьях?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP напрочь забыл. Но думаю идея ясна.
Как-то так

```
if (mysql_query("INSERT INTO friends (add_fri,friend) VALUES ('$add','$friend')")) {
    print "Теперь у Вас есть новый друг";
} else {
    if (mysql_errno() == 1169) {
        print "Это старый друг";
    } else {
        print "Какая-то непонятная ошибка";
    }
}
```

При наличии ограничения уникальности по паре (add_fri, friend). И только по ней. Иначе не разберёшь (чрезвычайно сложно) по какой именно причине возникла ошибка 1169. А так это будет единственная её причина.
Кстати номер ошибки желательно уточнить в руководстве или методом научного тыка в консоли SQL сервера.

Comment: Всё заработало спс.Не знал что внутри if можно сделать запрос).

Comment: Да. Можно. Можно и вне `if`: `$r = mysql_query(...); if ($r) { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

Не выводите кнопку добавления, если игрок уже в друзьях, и все. Зачем усложнять? На сервере при добавлении так же проверяйте, есть ли уже в базе такая запись, на случай высоконагруженного приложения можно использовать транзакции. И да, первичный ключ на уровне базы должен быть обязательно.

И используйте лучше PDO вместо mysql_query, или хотя бы на mysqli_query, иначе будут проблемы на последних версиях интерпретатора PHP.

Comment: Это конечно всё правильно про кнопку. Но с другой стороны ничто не мешает открыть страницу в двух окошках. В одной добавить друга и когда кнопка пропадёт, переключиться во второе окошко. А во втором окошке опять будет эта кнопка.

Comment: Так я и пишу, делайте серверную проверку на этот случай, от одного SELECT COUNT(*) хуже не будет, и если запись уже добавлена, возвращайте соответствующий ответ. Если для вас принципиально важна еще проверка на одновременную запись, изучите механизм Locker-ов, или транзакций

Comment: Мы сторонники оптимистичных блокировок. Локеры и транзакции уровня serializable только в крайних случаях. Добавление друга к ним не относится. На фига стоять в очереди блокировок/транзакций, если даже отрицательный результат - это тоже хорошо. даже лучше.

Comment: Хотел сделать если он уже в друзьях то пусть выводит кнопку " - " то есть удалить из друзей.Но х3 как мозг замерз)...

Comment: Кроме того возможны проблемы и в рамках одной транзакции (ошибки программиста там). В любом случае надо быть готовым к столкновению с ошибками/исключениями и уметь их обрабатывать. Да и транзакции для новичка - это тоже не просто.

Comment: Да, согласен, транзакции тоже нужно правильно применить. 
Хотя по мне, доводить PHP-обработку до уровня ошибок MySQL - тоже не лучший стиль. Но в данном случае стиль, как я понимаю, не так важен, поэтому можно и так.

Comment: @Sauron - сделайте проверку на выдачу корректной кнопки. Это usability, пользователь, у которого после добавления останется кнопка "добавить", будет недоумевать, добавил или нет.

Comment: Всё решил проблему сделал кнопку удаления и добавления